# Ways to filter a df, manipulate its content and then apply those changes to the original df?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I need to do some missing value imputation using *ffill* and *bfill* to a specific part of DF1. I need to filter a column ("Letters") by some text ("A", "B", individually). Once filtered, I need to replace missing values in column "Values" using ffill, and bfill. After that, I need to merge this new, filtered DF2 to the original DF1.

How can I achieve this? I´m stuck, unable to replace the DF2 values in DF1.

```
Index Letters Values
1     A       3
2     A       NaN
3     B       NaN
4     B       5
5     B       6
6     A       8
7     A       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to do it with pd.update()!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).